# how to deploy a fabric application in a particular node(say Node0 or Node1) in service fabric cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I want to know that is there any possibility that i can deploy a fabric application in any particular node in service fabric cluster. i.e. in one Node only one application should deploy.
   If InstanceCount = "1",it is deploying in one node,But any other application also can deploy in that same node.So if i have 5 application,and if there are 5 node in cluster,each node should have only one application.
  Can i mention the Node name anywhere in the code before deploying it as a solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to deploy an application to a specific node? There are some good answers here about placement constraints but depending on what you want to do there may be better options.

Answer (score 3):

Applications are just logical containers, deployment units. They aren't tied to nodes. Services (replicas and instances) are.

Generally, if you put 5 applications on your cluster, the cluster will automatically distribute services across all nodes.

There's a feature called [placement constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#placement-constraints-and-node-properties) that you can use to put services in designated nodes.

It's unwise to restrict service placement without **explicitly** needing it because:

- automatic balancing - Service Fabric makes sure resource use is optimized
  Adding placement constraints limit the options to balance.
- replication - Service Fabric replicates data from stateful services/actors across nodes to increase availability and to deal with node failures.
  Adding placement constraints limits the options to replicate.
- high availability - Service Fabric can detect node failures and move your service to a healthy node. Adding placement constraints limits the options to move services.

Comment: Ya, i got it.Thanks LoekD.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-resource-manager-cluster-description#placement-constraints-and-node-properties

> "You shouldn't usually be constraining services to run on a single
>   node since that prevents high availability, and you shouldn't be
>   manually configuring individual nodes.  ... this is an anti-pattern
>   since it couples your application type to your environment (what if
>   the nodes are named differently in a different environment?) and adds
>   additional complexity (since now you must manage all of this as
>   application parameters)."